# Typescript pushing into array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

This is how i declare array under class:

```
    pastq:number[];
randomqnumber:number;
```

inside one functions else statement:

```
this.randomqnumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * homework.length)+1;
  console.log(this.randomqnumber);//got the number
  this.pastq.push(this.randomqnumber); // not working
  console.log(this.pastq[0]); //not working
```

Comment: Please describe what 'not working' means in this case, whats happening/not happening? are you getting any errors reported?

Answer (score 7):

I think you forget to initialize your array.

```
pastq:number[] = [];
```